# Expand multi-value dropdown in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, filter, parameters, width, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using a multi-value filtering on my SSRS report. All of the selections is long. There is a scroll pane available but users find it very painful to scroll all the way just to determine which to select.

Is there a way to expand the width of the filter?

If I am using single value filter, there is no issue. The dropdown box will expand according to the longest length.

Comment: Check [this](http://blogs.harvard.edu/brandonhaynes/2008/09/24/changing-the-size-of-reportviewer-parameter-dropdown-list/), it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't increase the size of parameter. that's limitation we have in SSRS.Parameter options are not in our control :( :(

Answer (score 0):

In case others are looking for SSRS 2016 (and probably other versions) this can be done globally by adding a style to the HtmlView.css file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Styles (or appropriate directory depending on your version).

```
div[id$="divDropDown"] > span > div:first-child {
     width: 330px !important;
     height: 300px !important;
}
```

You can create your own additional custom styles (and modify existing styles) by copying all the styling from HtmlView.css to your own CSS file in the same directory. You'll then need to reference the custom CSS file in the rsreportserver.config file by adding an override in the main  element:

```
<Configuration>
     <HTMLViewerStyleSheet>Custom CSS Filename (without extension)</HTMLViewerStyleSheet>
```